# JavaScript REGEX negative look ahead confusion

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

OK I processing some lines with JavaScript and wanted to use a negative look ahead to eliminate the line if it contained a particular phrase but I still seem to be grabbing the lines and regexbuddy and others show it matching and I am not sure why

```
^This (\w+) (\w+) was built in (\d+). (.+?).(?! This car has a salvage title.)$
```

So I need to grab some various second sentence values that are to varied to match thus the (.+?). 
what I don't want is if the line contains has the reference to the salvage title

SO

```
This Honda Accord was built in 1986. This car has 3 accidents. This car has a salvage title.
```

should not match because the negative look ahead should fail

but

```
This Honda Accord was built in 1986. This car has 3 accidents.
```

should match but I am getting matches on both. Am I just mis-understanding the negative look ahead or am I mis-formatting it?

Comment: not sure if it's related to the problem, but you need to escape the `.` characters that you want to match literally.

Comment: I've tried them using \. as well and still failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> …(?! This car has a salvage title.)$
> ```

You've put the negative lookahead right before the end of the string. It will *always* not match there (i.e. succeed). It's a lookahead after all, not a lookbehind, and peeking behind the end of the string doesn't make sense.

You probably wanted to do this instead:

```
^This (\w+) (\w+) was built in (\d+)\. (?!This car has a salvage title)(.+?)\.$
```

Here, the `(?!This car has a salvage title)(.+?)` does match the sentence (precisely, at least one character) before the dot, which does not begin with the phrase "This car has a salvage title". Or, if you don't want that phrase anywhere after the first sentence, then use

```
^This (\w+) (\w+) was built in (\d+)\. (?!.*?This car has a salvage title)(.+?)\.$
//                                        ^^^
```